# How to convert webpage table data to json object or dict in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-2.7, urllib2

I am trying to fetch data from webpage which contains table and then compare values in table with other table values.
Can I convert webpage into json data or dictionary in python? 
e.g. I have url `www.yahoo.com` how can I covert html data into json?
I tried

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

data = str(response.read())
```

I get html output. If I try `json.loads(data)` I get error `raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")`

Is there way to pull data from table which is displayed on webpage

Answer (score 0):

Use beautifulsoup (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract the table then convert it. Try [Convert a HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544634/convert-a-html-table-to-json); it shows how to use beautifulsoup to grab the table and convert it into JSON.