# How can I scrape data from an HTML table into a Python list/dict?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to import data from [Baseball Prospectus](https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/card/70917/trea-turner) into a Python table / dictionary (which would be better?).

Below is what I have, based on following along to Automate The Boring Stuff with Python.

I get that my method isn't properly using these functions, but I can't figure out what tools I should be using.

```
import requests
import webbrowser
import bs4

res = requests.get('https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/card/70917/trea-turner')
res.raise_for_status()
webpage = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
table = webpage.select('newstat_career_log_datagrid')
list = []
for item in table:
    list.append(item)

print(list)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544634/convert-a-html-table-to-json here you go, after that you have JSON, which is acctualy a python dict :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a HTML Table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544634/convert-a-html-table-to-json)

Comment: Which of the tables on the page are you looking to scrape?

Comment: @JackFleeting The top one, "MLB Statistics," ID = ```stats_card_standard_datagrid```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas Data Frame to fetch the `MLB Statistics` table first and then convert dataframe into dictionary object.If you don't have pandas install you can do it in a single command.

```
 pip install pandas
```

Then use the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_html('https://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/card/70917/trea-turner')
data_dict = df[5].to_dict()
print(data_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'PA': {0: 44, 1: 324, 2: 447, 3: 740, 4: 15, 5: 1570}, '2B': {0: 1, 1: 14, 2: 24, 3: 27, 4: 1, 5: 67}, 'TEAM': {0: 'WAS', 1: 'WAS', 2: 'WAS', 3: 'WAS', 4: 'WAS', 5: 'Career'}, 'SB': {0: 2, 1: 33, 2: 46, 3: 43, 4: 4, 5: 128}, 'G': {0: 27, 1: 73, 2: 98, 3: 162, 4: 4, 5: 364}, 'HR': {0: 1, 1: 13, 2: 11, 3: 19, 4: 2, 5: 46}, 'FRAA': {0: 0.5, 1: -3.2, 2: 0.2, 3: 7.1, 4: -0.1, 5: 4.5}, 'BWARP': {0: 0.1, 1: 2.4, 2: 2.7, 3: 5.0, 4: 0.1, 5: 10.4}, 'CS': {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 0, 5: 25}, '3B': {0: 0, 1: 8, 2: 6, 3: 6, 4: 0, 5: 20}, 'H': {0: 9, 1: 105, 2: 117, 3: 180, 4: 5, 5: 416}, 'AGE': {0: '22', 1: '23', 2: '24', 3: '25', 4: '26', 5: 'Career'}, 'OBP': {0: 0.295, 1: 0.37, 2: 0.33799999999999997, 3: 0.344, 4: 0.4, 5: 0.34700000000000003}, 'AVG': {0: 0.225, 1: 0.342, 2: 0.284, 3: 0.271, 4: 0.35700000000000004, 5: 0.289}, 'DRC+': {0: 77, 1: 128, 2: 99, 3: 107, 4: 103, 5: 108}, 'SO': {0: 12, 1: 59, 2: 80, 3: 132, 4: 5, 5: 288}, 'YEAR': {0: '2015', 1: '2016', 2: '2017', 3: '2018', 4: '2019', 5: 'Career'}, 'SLG': {0: 0.325, 1: 0.5670000000000001, 2: 0.451, 3: 0.41600000000000004, 4: 0.857, 5: 0.46}, 'DRAA': {0: -1.0, 1: 11.4, 2: 1.0, 3: 8.5, 4: 0.1, 5: 20.0}, 'HBP': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 0, 5: 10}, 'BRR': {0: 0.1, 1: 5.9, 2: 6.8, 3: 2.7, 4: 0.2, 5: 15.7}, 'BB': {0: 4, 1: 14, 2: 30, 3: 69, 4: 1, 5: 118}}
```